# How to specify ConnectTimeout for dropbear?

Tags: ssh, timeout, dropbear

I'm trying to use the Dropbear SSH and in the previous version of SSH I used, you could add the argument `-o ConnectTimeout=10` to cause an attempted connection to timeout if unsuccessful after ten seconds.

Is there a way to programmatically specify a connection timeout when using Dropbear SSH?

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the code, it appears that the only timeout you can configure on the client side is the idle timeout, which you can configure with the `-I` option followed by the idle timeout in seconds.

On the server side there's a timeout which kills incoming connections if the client doesn't authenticate within five minutes, but it's not configurable at runtime; you'd need to edit `sysoptions.h` and rebuild. The only command-line configurable timeout on the server side is the idle timeout, in the same way as on the client.